# Wrapping sum and calculation with ISNULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to replace null values from this code with zero

```
SUM(ITR_TransQty * - 1)
```

I tried wrapping it in ISNULL but I'm still returning null values

```
ISNULL(SUM(ITR_TransQty * - 1),0)
```

Am i missing something in my code, or is will this not work b/c of the calculation in the sum expression?

thanks!

update with full query

```
SELECT pod.POD_ItemID, pod.POD_PurchOrderID, pod.POD_RequiredDate,    pod.POD_RequiredQty, (pod.POD_RequiredQty * item.IMA_AcctValAmt) as OrderValue, 
((item.IMA_OrderPointQty * 2) + item.IMA_OnHandQty) AS MaxOHLogic, (item.IMA_AcctValAmt * item.IMA_OnHandQty) as OnHandValue, 
item.IMA_BuyerPlanner, aa.Last90, bb.Last180  
from 
POD INNER JOIN Item on IMA_ItemID = pod.POD_ItemID
left outer join
(SELECT     ITR_ItemID AS Item, ISNULL(SUM(ITR_TransQty * - 1),0) AS Last90
FROM          dbo.ITR (NOLOCK) 
WHERE      (ITR_TransDate BETWEEN GETDATE() - 92 AND GETDATE() - 2) AND 
(ITR_TransType LIKE N'Issue' OR
ITR_TransType LIKE N'Shipment')GROUP BY ITR_ItemID) AS aa ON dbo.Item.IMA_ItemID = aa.Item 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT     ITR_ItemID AS Item, SUM(ITR_TransQty) * - 1 AS Last180
FROM          dbo.ITR (NOLOCK) 
WHERE      (ITR_TransDate BETWEEN GETDATE() - 183 AND GETDATE() - 93) AND (ITR_TransType LIKE N'Issue' OR
ITR_TransType LIKE N'Shipment')
GROUP BY ITR_ItemID) AS bb ON dbo.Item.IMA_ItemID = bb.Item
WHERE ((Item.IMA_OrderPointQty * 2) <= item.IMA_OnHandQty) AND (pod.POD_RequiredDate >= GETDATE()-30) AND (pod.POD_RequiredDate <=
GETDATE()+90) AND (pod.POD_CompleteFlag <> 1)
order by OrderValue desc
```

Changed code to SUM(ISNULL(ITR_TransQty, 0) * - 1) and I'm still returning NULL values. I just checked the column and found that it is FLOAT rather than INT, I guess i will need to convert it first right?

Comment: There's got to be more to your query than that.  How about including some sample data, the full query?

Comment: `ISNULL(SUM(ITR_TransQty * - 1),0)` is fine. `NULL` values are ignored in aggregation, so the `ISNULL()` only gets used if there are no populated values for `ITR_TransQty`.

Comment: I believe Goat CO has the correct answer for you atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap aa.Last90 in the outer select with ISNULL instead, because you are using a left outer join.

```
SELECT pod.POD_ItemID, pod.POD_PurchOrderID, pod.POD_RequiredDate,    pod.POD_RequiredQty, (pod.POD_RequiredQty * item.IMA_AcctValAmt) as OrderValue, 
((item.IMA_OrderPointQty * 2) + item.IMA_OnHandQty) AS MaxOHLogic, (item.IMA_AcctValAmt * item.IMA_OnHandQty) as OnHandValue, 
item.IMA_BuyerPlanner, ISNULL(aa.Last90, 0) AS [Last90], bb.Last180  
from 
POD INNER JOIN Item on IMA_ItemID = pod.POD_ItemID
left outer join
(SELECT     ITR_ItemID AS Item, SUM(ITR_TransQty * - 1) AS Last90
FROM          dbo.ITR (NOLOCK) 
WHERE      (ITR_TransDate BETWEEN GETDATE() - 92 AND GETDATE() - 2) AND 
(ITR_TransType LIKE N'Issue' OR
ITR_TransType LIKE N'Shipment')GROUP BY ITR_ItemID) AS aa ON dbo.Item.IMA_ItemID = aa.Item 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT     ITR_ItemID AS Item, SUM(ITR_TransQty) * - 1 AS Last180
FROM          dbo.ITR (NOLOCK) 
WHERE      (ITR_TransDate BETWEEN GETDATE() - 183 AND GETDATE() - 93) AND (ITR_TransType LIKE N'Issue' OR
ITR_TransType LIKE N'Shipment')
GROUP BY ITR_ItemID) AS bb ON dbo.Item.IMA_ItemID = bb.Item
WHERE ((Item.IMA_OrderPointQty * 2) <= item.IMA_OnHandQty) AND (pod.POD_RequiredDate >= GETDATE()-30) AND (pod.POD_RequiredDate <=
GETDATE()+90) AND (pod.POD_CompleteFlag <> 1)
order by OrderValue desc
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with using:

```
ISNULL(SUM(ITR_TransQty * - 1),0)
```

`NULL` values are ignored in aggregation, so the `ISNULL()` is only utilized if all values of `ITR_TransQty` are `NULL`.

The reason you are returning `NULL` values is that you are selecting the aggregate in a subquery that you are then using a `LEFT JOIN` to get to.

You'll need to use `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` in your `SELECT` list to remove that `NULL`:

```
    SELECT pod.POD_ItemID, pod.POD_PurchOrderID, pod.POD_RequiredDate,    pod.POD_RequiredQty, (pod.POD_RequiredQty * item.IMA_AcctValAmt) as OrderValue, 
    ((item.IMA_OrderPointQty * 2) + item.IMA_OnHandQty) AS MaxOHLogic, (item.IMA_AcctValAmt * item.IMA_OnHandQty) as OnHandValue, 
    item.IMA_BuyerPlanner
   , ISNULL(aa.Last90,0) AS Last90  
   , bb.Last180  
    FROM ...
```

This change will make the `ISNULL()` around your aggregate redundant, so you can remove it.